# Is there a --max-requests flag for Daphne?

Tags: django, channel, daphne

I have this ASGI applicate with Django and Daphne, and I'm using the following command.

```
daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p $PORT server.asgi:application
```

Is there a way to add `--max-requests` and `--max-requests-jitter` to actively prevent memory leaks? Maybe something like:

```
daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p $PORT --max-requests 1000 --max-requests-jitter 50 server.asgi:application
```